# Why is this .csv file not woking in Weka?

Tags: database, csv, data-mining, weka, arff

I am working on a data mining project using Python sci kit and Weka. The dataset I am using is text-file and I have converted it to CSV using Python (with Pandas library). Unfortunately when I try to run it through Weka, the program says that. it cannot convert my file. I have attached the link with the replit that I converted the file to csv on: [LINK](https://replit.com/join/gwxpehhjsb-wroughtbarrows0)

I have tried manually converting it (which takes forever) and it still did not run. I have also tried converting it in a csv to .arff file for Weka which also did not work. I am so stressed! I do not understand why this is not working! I appreciate all the help I can get!!

Comment: The file is not accessible without login. Have you tried the loader from the [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) Weka package instead of Weka's own CSVLoader?